# How Thread.currentThread().getName() implemented in java?

Tags: java

Here i am trying to understand How java implementing `Thread.currentThread().getName()`

I am able to understand `Thread.currentThread()` from this `<class-name>.<method-name>`. But how they are calling final method getName() called `<class-name>.<static_method-name>.<methodName>` ?

What is this Java Concept?.

So that i can refer more.

Comment: Sorry, you may need to be more specific? Thread::getName is a public method; the final keyword affects only the ability of subclasses to override the method, not the ability to access it

Comment: Thread.currentThread() returns an object of type Thread. The getName() method is called on that object. Think of it as 2 separate statements. `Thread current = Thread.currentThread(); String name = current.getName();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.currentThread()` will return `Thread` Object, `getName` is it's instance method.

```
Thread t = Thread.currentThread()
t.getName()
```

Answer (score 2):

`currentThread()` returns an instance of a `Thread` class, which has a `getName()` method.

There's no limit to the number of methods that can be "chained" as long as you are dealing with Objects

A "final method" doesn't affect this fact

Answer (score 2):

When a new thread is crated without any name.

Then,

```
  public Thread() {
        init(null, null, "Thread-" + nextThreadNum(), 0);
    }
```

A name will be assigned like : `Thread-<some number>`

Now when a Thread.currentThread() is called a Thread object is returned. The Thread class has getName() method, which returns the name.

You can refer to the Thread class code from the java source code.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.getCurrentThread()` returns a `Thread` object. Then immediately, the method `getName()` is invoked on it. These two code fragments do the same:

```
String n = Thread.currentThread().getName();
```

And:

```
Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
String n = t.getName();
```

Don't be tempted to do this everywhere though. `NullPointerExceptions` will happen if you do this when the first method returns null and you invoke the second method on it.

A common practice for this type of method chaining is found in the Builder pattern where methods are garantueed never to return `null`.